# Derivation of pressure of a gas from mean sqaured speed of molecules

Tags: pressure, velocity, kinetic-theory, gas

I understand that the pressure exerted by a molecule on the walls of a container, in the $x$ direction is given by
$P=n m v_x^2$
Where $v_x$ is the mean $x$ component of velocity, $m$ is mass and $n$ is the number of molecules.

I also understand that $\mathbf{v_x^2=v_y^2=v_z^2}$

What I'm unable to understand is this:
$\mathbf{\frac{1}{3}(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)=\frac{1}{3}v^2}$
Why exactly are we multiplying the equation by $\frac{1}{3}$ ? Apparently it is to find the average.
But $(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)$ gives us the resultant velocity sqaured in magnitude. Dividing it by $3$ would just be reducing its value by one-third. How do we get the average by multiplying by $\frac{1}{3}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with how the total velocity is worked out from the components, with Pythagoras theorem.  $v^2 = {v_x}^2+{v_y}^2+{v_z}^2$

If the components are equal on average then $v^2 = 3{v_x}^2$ and ${v_x}^2 = \frac{1}{3}{v}^2$

The second formula in bold in the question is best written omitting the $\frac{1}{3}$ from each side and your first formula for P becomes $P=\frac{1}{3}mnv^2$